# Encode Android AudioRecord raw pcm data to other format using ffmpeg

Tags: android, audio, video, encoding, ffmpeg

I am using AudioRecord class to read the data in bytes. Since the data received in the AudioRecord.read(byte[], int, int) is in raw form(too big), I want to encode it in some other compressed format like Vorbis(.ogg) using ffmpeg C Api. I have compiled the libffmpeg.so file which I will call through JNI. I want to know how this will be done.

After successfully encoding I want to create a video with this same audio and a single image attached to it.

Thanks.

Comment: and what precisely is the question here?

Comment: Simply just create an audio file "test.ogg" with the raw data that I got using AudioRecord.read(byte[], int, int). 
And after that create a video file "video1.3gp" with the audio that was saved in "test.ogg".

Comment: THat's a pretty broad question.  Have you made an attempt at doing this yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a .wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179536/writing-pcm-recorded-data-into-a-wav-file-java-android) with your data in bytes and later convert this audio file with your image directly in a video. [1 image + 1 audio file = 1 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887311/ffmpeg-1-image-1-audio-file-1-video)